# Could not find method in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.ImageView

Tags: java, android, view, imageview, android-view

I basically just call this in the android:onClick function in my XML for this particular ImageView: `android:onClick="SendGetStartedNotification"`. But because my function has two parameters, I get this error `Method has incorrect signature`. It wants me to removed the ParseUser class.

```
public void SendGetStartedNotification(View view, ParseUser user) {

    // initiate installation query
    ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query  = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("userId", user.getUserObject());

    // send push notification
    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setQuery(query);
    push.setMessage(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername() + " " + "thinks you should create something!");
    push.sendInBackground();

    // send notification to NotificationsActivity
    ParseObject notification = createGetStartedMessage(view, user);
    send(notification);
}
```

The problem is my error message:

```
12-20 22:22:37.349  29251-29251/com.app.testE/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.test, PID: 29251
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method SendGetStartedNotification(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.ImageView with id 'messageGallerySave2'
            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:4485)
            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4449)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

What are my alternatives? Setting an onClick listener programatically doesn't seem to be working either. What should I do?

**Update:** I'm using an AsyncTask to bring user information in my class.

```
private class GetParseUserInformationTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Design, ParseUser> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GalleryActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Designs...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected ParseUser doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ParseUser parseUser = null;

            // gather User information and then fetch the designs for them
            try {
                parseUser = ParseHelper.GetUserInformation(userObjectId);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return parseUser;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ParseUser user) {

            if(user == null) {
                //todo: some error message
                return;
            }

            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.fullName)).setText(user.getName());
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.bio)).setText(user.getBio());
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.websiteLink)).setText(user.getWebsiteLink());
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.username)).setText(user.getUsername());
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.saves_number)).setText(user.getFeedDesignSaves().toString());
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.designs_number)).setText(String.valueOf(ParseHelper.GetUserDesignsCount(user.getUserObject())));
            ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profile_picture)).setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(user.getProfilePictureURL()));

            // asynchronously display the profile picture downloaded from parse
            if(user.getProfilePictureURL() != null) {
                profilePictureImageLoader.DisplayImage(user.getProfilePictureURL(), ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture)), null);
            }

            new GetParseUserDesignsTask().execute(user);

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you use your method with `ParseUser`,once `onClick` is triggered how can you get the value of  `ParseUser`.

Comment: Hmm... Not sure. See my update. I'm using an AsyncTask method to bring the user information into my class.

Comment: but this doesn't relevant to your `onClick` method......I think you'd better remove the `ParseUser` parameter in `SendGetStartedNotification`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Click listener on button.

```
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
SendGetStartedNotification(ParseUser user);

                    }
                } );
```

Make your method like this:

```
public void SendGetStartedNotification(ParseUser user) {

    // initiate installation query
    ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query  = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("userId", user.getUserObject());

    // send push notification
    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setQuery(query);
    push.setMessage(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername() + " " + "thinks you should create something!");
    push.sendInBackground();

    // send notification to NotificationsActivity
    ParseObject notification = createGetStartedMessage(view, user);
    send(notification);
}
```

Comment: Right. This clears things up, but the problem is my ParseUser isn't initialized properly. I suppose that's a different question though.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would do that based on my AsyncTask? The profile doesn't belong to the current user so I can't just do that.

Comment: why are you calling GetParseUserDesignsTask() class in onPostexecute method. Instead you should call it in SendGetStartedNotification();. I guess!!